# Why do I receive the colors black and yellow on a scatterplot when a run plyplot.scatter where c is equal to a list of ones and zeros?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

The code below prints out a scatterplot of black and yellow circles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
           
x = [65,70,30,80,20,90,10,10,5,85]
y = [30,20,60,10,70,5,80,70,70,10]
temple_type = [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
    
plt.scatter(x  , y  , c=temple_type, edgecolor ="black" , s = 80)
```

Comment: What colors were you expecting to "receive"?

Comment: They are purple and yellow. Sequential numbers to c have `viridis` as the colors, otherwise it's `tab10`. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#overview

Answer (score 1):

You receive the colors corresponding to the high and low values for the colormap you are using. By default you are using the `"viridis"` colormap.

You can change the [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) using the `cmap` argument:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [65, 70, 30, 80, 20, 90, 10, 10, 5, 85]
y = [30, 20, 60, 10, 70, 5, 80, 70, 70, 10]
temple_type = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

fig, (ax1, ax2)  = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))

s1 = ax1.scatter(x, y, c=temple_type, edgecolor="black", s=80, cmap="viridis")
fig.colorbar(s1)

s2 = ax2.scatter(x, y, c=temple_type, edgecolor="black", s=80, cmap="Blues")
fig.colorbar(s2)

plt.show()
```

[image: viridis and blues cmaps]